# Lua table based OOP: Two versions

Tags: oop, lua, lua-table

At the internet I have found two different solutions for make table based oop in Lua. I saw that the method calls are similar but the 'constructors' are quiet different.

I would to know which solution has more advantages/is the better one. I know there is a also a closure based oop in Lua, but here I'm only interested in the table based solutions.

Version 1 (I prefer this syntax)

```
Citizen = {name}

--Constructor
function Citizen:new(o, name)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  o.name = name
  return o
end

--Getters--
function Citizen:getName()
  return self.name
end
...
```

Version 2

```
Citizen = {}
Citizen.__index = Citizen

setmetatable(Citizen, {
  __call = function(cls, ...)
  local self = setmetatable({}, cls)
  self:_init(...)
  return self
  end,
})

--Constructor--
function Citizen:_init(name)
  self.name = name
end

--Getters--
function Citizen:getName()
  return self.name
end
...
```

Comment: IMO, there are no advantages or disadvantages: these two variants are almost the same.  The only minor difference is constructor invocation: `Citizen:new()` vs `Citizen()`.  It's a matter of taste.